# JS function always keep executing code at the start of my html

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS, I watched some crash course on YouTube and try to do it on the same time. I'm using Visual Studio Code with an extension `live server` in order to see changes quickly.

In my JS code:

```
    //SUBSCRIBE
    var subscribeEmail = document.getElementById('subscribe-email');
    var subscribeSubmit = document.getElementById('subsribe-link-btn');

//HEADER
    var headerRootWrapper = document.getElementById("navbar-wrapper");
    console.log(headerRootWrapper);
    var show = document.getElementById('sidebar-wrapper');

//LOGO
    var webLogo = document.getElementById('logo');
    console.log(webLogo);

//MENU BAR
    var menuBar = document.getElementById('menu-bar').addEventListener('click', menuSlideLeft());
    console.log(menuBar);
    var sideMenuId = document.getElementById('sidebar-wrapper');

//SEARCH BAR
    var searchBar = document.getElementById('searchBarShow').addEventListener('click',searchStart());

// METHOD 
    function menuSlideLeft() {
        alert("Fire");

}
```

From my Html file, I added the js script at the bottom (not inside the body tag) . It always execute the method `menuSlideLeft()` at the start without making me click the menuBar.

```
<script src="js/jscript.js"></script>
```

[image: js]

Comment: `addEventListener('click', menuSlideLeft())` remove `()` from `menuSlideLeft()`. Use like `addEventListener('click', menuSlideLeft)` , same for `addEventListener('click',searchStart)`

Comment: You're adding an event listener with the *output* of `menuSlideLeft` as the handler.  It's subtle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the parentheses from your event listener, that calls the function. Instead use:

```
.addEventListener('click', menuSlideLeft);
```

Answer (score 4):

You are calling function in this line

```
var menuBar = document.getElementById('menu-bar').addEventListener('click', menuSlideLeft());
```

check the part `menuSlideLeft()` in `addEventListener` function.

What you should do is

```
 var menuBar = document.getElementById('menu-bar').addEventListener('click', menuSlideLeft);
```

i-e just pass the reference of the function. Don't call it. it will be called in that event

Answer (score 1):

You are calling function instead of passing it as parameter.
Solution:

```
document.getElementById('menu-bar').addEventListener('click', menuSlideLeft);
```